# SWT: KeyPressed Event After Done

Tags: java, swt, keypress, event-handling

I'm creating a text box that automatically completes the input from a list.  For example, if you enter `345`, it might check the list and find `345678`, and then the text box has `345`, and then `678` highlighted.

http://nucleussystems.com/files/Screenshot.png

This way, if you continue typing something different, it removes the automatically appended text.

I tried doing it with the keyReleased event, but there were user experience problems if more than one key was pressed at a time (something very common when typing fast).  But I soon found out that the keyPressed event doesn't add the text typed until after the event handler(s) is/are called.

So I need to find out a way to fire my event handler *after* SWT has handled it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *SWT.Modify* event can provide what you need. Have a look at the [ModifyListener](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/ModifyListener.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.  Just a little logic adjustment and everything works perfectly.